# Doing an operation to every number in a subscript

Tags: notation, summation

I'm not good with words, and neither with math, but I'll do my best. (If someone has a better title for this then...). I've been learning about subscripts recently, and things like $\sum$ and $\prod$. But is there a way to manipulate all in a subset? If you didn't get that, let's say we have $X_{1} = 5, X_{2} = 2,$ and $X_{3} = 6$. I could use summation to add all of them up and get 13. But what if I want to $(* 3) + 1$ on all of them at once? And then $\sum X = 40$?

Comment: i already have figured out how to fix this in the equation I need it in ($P_{N} = (P_{1}-[N-1]) * (U-N-1)$)... but now really I'm asking if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure to understand your question
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 3X_i\right) + 1 = 3X_1 + 3X_2 + 3X_3 + 1 = 40$$

Comment: (I'm no math guy, but I code so I'm just gonna say execute, hopefully you'll understand.) This executes the equation on every individual number in the subset and then adds them together?

Comment: I tried to clarify it further.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still have quite a bit more to learn, huh.